# How does one find the extinction coefficient of a particular galaxy?

Tags: galaxy, deep-sky-observing, resource-request, extinction, photometry

I am doing photometry on a number of objects in a number of different galaxies. I need the extinction coefficients for these galaxies for various filters passes. Is there some database that displays extinction values for different galaxies at different filter passes?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Extinction has two components, one through our own galaxy, and then extinction in the external galaxy. The first is likely similar for all objects in a single external galaxy, the second could vary (a lot if it's a spiral).